# WNetGetConnection and run as admin

Tags: winapi

I need to call `WNetGetConnection` to get the UNC path and it works good when application run as standard user but it returns `1201`(ERROR_CONNECTION_UNAVAIL) error code when application run as admin. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385453%28VS.85%29.aspx) its working as expected.

> If the network connection was made using the Microsoft LAN Manager
>   network, and the calling application is running in a different logon
>   session than the application that made the connection, a call to the
>   WNetGetConnection function for the associated local device will fail.
>   The function fails with ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED or
>   ERROR_CONNECTION_UNAVAIL. This is because a connection made using
>   Microsoft LAN Manager is visible only to applications running in the
>   same logon session as the application that made the connection. (To
>   prevent the call to WNetGetConnection from failing it is not
>   sufficient for the application to be running in the user account that
>   created the connection.)

that means its not possible at all to get the UNC path from the app running as admin ? Is there some other way ?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. Network shares created by a non-elevated account are not visible under elevation, and vice versa.

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/105173/how-to-access-network-shares-from-an-elevated-process-in-windows-7) on Super User for discussion of the issue. There is apparently a registry setting that enables mapped drives to be shared between elevated and non-elevated accounts but I've never tried it myself.

Comment: True but its strange because I see no point why its so. Because I logged in with admin account, I created the share and I can not access it with admin rights. But I can with standard rights. Its kind of doing opposite. If I created the share with admin rights why its letting standard user work but not the admin and if Explorer created the share using standard rights then admin should have full access because its admin ?

Comment: That's the point of UAC. Even an admin account does not have admin rights if unelevated.

Comment: It still makes no sense. I tried making Network Drive using elevated process. It works good but after restart. It still working only with standard user. Why ? Because MS LAN Manager gets connected to it on logon as standard user. Now whats the point again ? I created the share using elevated process.

Answer (score 0):

Network connections cannot normally be shared across different Windows login sessions. This is regardless of admin account / elevation level. Each Windows login or impersonation session needs to create its own network connections.