# Can't run file as Admin but OK if I run as a normal user

Tags: windows, cmd, administrator

> EDIT: Tried this: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>runas /user:gabs-pc\gabs-pc "J:\TI\...\Editor_PDF\editor_pdf.exe"`
>
> Got this error: "The system could not fin the specified file."

Pretty hard to expose my problem on the topic title...

Well... I have a *.exe* file that I want to run, this file is in a shared hard drive through a local network called **J:\**.

If I open my cmd prompt as a normal user in a given path and I try to execute the .exe file using, for example:

```
"J:\TI\Estágio\gabriel\Editor de PDF\Editor PDF\editor_pdf.exe" param1 param2 param3
```

It works fine. But when I try to run the exact same file, from the same computer opening the cmd prompt as an Administrator I get the following error:

> '"J:\TI...\Editor PDF\editor_pdf.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an operable program or a batch file.

I would like to know how to execute that file as an administrator OR a single-line workaround to run that file as the current/normal user.

**Comments.:** If some of you are asking yourselves "why don't you just open cmd as a normal user?". I'm trying to call this program from another program which can only run cmd as an Administrator, that's why.

Comment: `this file is in a shared hard drive` - shared drives is per user - admin user not view normal user shared drives and visa versa

Comment: Local administrator has not administrator rights on network files if this is a Windows domain than you need to have domain administrator rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert network drive path into its real UNC path first. As @RbMm says, network drive is a per-use configuration.

If you stick to `cmd`, you may use `wmic path win32_mappedlogicaldisk get DeviceID, ProviderName` to retrieve the real path of target.

You may also use [Winapi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385453(v=vs.85).aspx) `WNetGetConnection` to retrieve the path of drive.

The process should **NOT** be done in Administrator context. If you cannot, you need to use `CreateProcessAsUser` to retrieve information from another user's perspective.

Pseudo code:

```
char path[260] = {0};
WNetGetConncetion ("J:", path, 260);
WinExec ("\"" + path + "\\TI\\Estágio\\gabriel\\Editor de PDF\\Editor PDF\\editor_pdf.exe"
       + "\" " + param1 + " " + param2 + " " + param3, SW_HIDE);
```

Additional information:

- [WNetGetConnection and run as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310400/wnetgetconnection-and-run-as-admin)
- [How to access network shares from an elevated process in Windows
  7?](https://superuser.com/questions/105173/how-to-access-network-shares-from-an-elevated-process-in-windows-7)